# Does anyone know how to demonstrate that the stereographic projection is antiholomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, cauchy-riemann-equations, stereographic-projections

I have the following function that is for the stereographic projection:
$$f(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{\kappa}(2x, 2y, x^2 + y^2 - 1)\hspace{0.3cm} \text{where} \hspace{0.3cm} \kappa = x^2 + y^2 + 1.$$
So let now I calculate the partial derivatives of the function, giving me this
$$Dfe_{1} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{2}{\kappa^2}(- x^2 + y^2 + 1, -2xy, 2x)$$
and
$$Dfe_{1} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{2}{\kappa^2}(-2xy,  x^2 - y^2 + 1, 2y)$$
where $e_{i}$ is a canonical basis which implies that $f$ is conformal.

I am trying to prove that the stereographic projection is antiholomorphic, due to the fact that by definition, the function is anticonformal (preserves magnitud of angles but changes the orientation). However, any holomorphic or antiholomorphic function is conformal, so I am trying to find the anticonformal property. Does anyone know how to demonstrate that the stereogrpahic projection is antiholomorphic but algebraically ?

The main reason I am trying to prove this is that I could use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show the sign of the Jacobean is strictly negative.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> "Holomorphic" isn't a property of a mapping unless complex structures are specified on the domain and codomain. Can you please add the necessary details to your question? Or, are you not asking about stereographic projection specifically, but about how to check a mapping is "anti-holomorphic"?

Comment: I am working on the Complex plane mapping points from this one to the Riemann Sphere. This mapping is called stereographic projection and by definition it is conformal but changes the orientation, meaning that it is anticonformal. And this implies that if it's anticonformal then the function is antiholomorfic. I am trying to demonstrate that the stereographic projection is antiholomorfic and that's it.

Comment: One stereograohic projection is orientation-preserving and the other is orientation-reversing. You need a complex structure on the sphere before you can say (anti]holomorphic. Have you written actual equations or drawn clear pictures?

Comment: Would it be correct if I consider it a manifold?